# Can resolution of optical microscope be improve by covering part of the objective?

Tags: optics

I've have been told that by covering part of the objective lens of an optical microscope, the resolution of the image can be improved. Is it really the case? If it does, what is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the quality of the lens of the microscope.

If it is optically "perfect", the resolution is limited by diffraction and reducing the aperture degrades the resolution.

But if there are significant geometric aberrations, reducing aperture can reduce these aberrations and improve resolution.

Comment: so in practical case, the lens being imperfect, reducing aperture does help reduce the aberration? I wonder to what extent can this method help improve the resolution. I think its small?

Comment: When we say "perfect" it means that the geometric aberrations are small enough that the diffraction limits the resolution. For an objective of reasonable quality, the aperture should have been adapted to the optical quality and it should be difficult to improve the resolution in this way. Not to mention the loss of brightness.

Comment: @phyphyphy This answer is correct. Lenses are usually made as a compromise where the sweet spot is a bit smaller than the maximum aperture. So reducing the aperture slightly may increase the sharpness, but at the expense of brightness. Any further reduction of the aperture would decrease the sharpness due to diffraction. Some lenses also are sharpest at the maximum aperture already. It all depends on the lens.